# Generate and Download PDF on ie8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf, internet-explorer-8

I am generating pdf from html using JavaScript,pdf generate working fine but can't download,download working fine Google chrome but not working on `ie8`,i also tried `jspdf` its working fine on chrome but its giving error on `ie8`.

i Google but couldn't fine solution,the main points is to download on `ie8`.

can you please suggest how i can resolve this issue ?
Thanks

This is my html

```
CompleteHTML =
                                "<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'><head><title></title></head><body>" +
                                       divcustmrDtls + "<div style='page-break-after: always;'></div> "
                                     + divfacilityDtls + "<div style='page-break-after: always;'></div> "
                                     + divcolltrlDtls + "<div style='page-break-after: always;'></div> "
                                     + divgroupDetails + "<div style='page-break-after: always;'></div> "
                                     + divgroupColDetails + "<div style='page-break-after: always;'></div> "
                                     + divAccntPlan + "<div style='page-break-after: always;'></div> "
                                     + divMemo + "<div style='page-break-after: always;'></div> "
                                     + divBIR ;
```

Comment: How does the download _work_? If it's a [Data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) then IE8 support is somewhat limited...

Comment: @BoristheSpider,simply convert html to pdf file both file download and print

Comment: @BoristheSpider,I am generating file on client side

Comment: Exactly. To provide a download of content generated on the client side, you need to somehow emulate a local resource as a remote one. This is usually done by generating a Data URI, and this method is not really supported by IE8.

Comment: @BoristheSpider can you please help me for any other solution?